# html website on the domain itself (without folders)

Tags: dns

after I uploaded an html file to the servers hosting my domain, for example a file named a.html uploaded to b.com, I need to type the url: b.com/a.html to see the contents of the file. But how can I have a website/content in b.com without any files? Meaning that when I search b.com I will see some content without adding "/a.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `a.html` to `index.html` (or create a new file). Then take a look a `b.com`.

When a webserver is pointed to a directory, it will look for a file with `index` as prefix. So when visiting `domain.com`, you will see the contents of `index.html`.

I found this at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/getting-started.html

> Typically, a document called index.html will be served when a directory is requested without a file name being specified. For example, if DocumentRoot is set to /var/www/html and a request is made for http://www.example.com/work/, the file /var/www/html/work/index.html will be served to the client.

Comment: Wait, but won't it simply redirect it to `b.com/index.html` ? Because I what I meant is to show only the domain, like in google.com for instance (it only shows google.com without directories and files).